# Writing to port 514 in AIX

Tags: tcp, aix

I need issue this command on AIX:

echo "foobar" | nc 191.168.100.1-u 514 -w 1

but AIX doesn´t have netcat.

Can you help me ?

Comment: So, why don't you install `netcat` then? Either via source or a package manager like [perzl.org](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php)? This is actually a question better suited for SuperUser or even ServerFault instead of StackOverflow, it's not about programming.

Comment: Unfortunately I can´t instal netcat in my system. (Security issues)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this also works on AIX (it does at least on Linux and Mac), but with `bash` you can do this:

```
echo "foobar" >/dev/udp/192.168.100.1/514
```

Note that you really need a `bash` or `ksh93` shell. It does not work with other shells.

Comment: I didn´t found a /dev/udp in my system :-(

Comment: You can't find it because it don't exist. It's a bash feature: the magic paths `/dev/udp/<host>/<port>` and `/dev/tcp/<host>/<port>` are interpreted and handled by bash. Which is why I explicitly stated that it does not work with other shells.